# Rails Model Validate Mutual Exclusivity for properties

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I have an `EventType` model that I want to ensure has only one of the following properties if any: `points_required` or `percentage_attendance_required`.

To clarify, `name` is always required. `points_required` is not required and neither is `percentage_attendance_required`. However, if either of those two are submitted, only one may be present.

There are only a few other questions out there similar to this that I could find and none of them have been helpful.

So far this is what I have in my EventType model:

```
validates :name, presence: true, length: { maximum: 50 }
validates :points_required, presence: true, length: {maximum: 2},
           numericality: { only_integer: true },
           if: Proc.new { |e| e.percentage_attendance_required.blank? }
validates :percentage_attendance_required, presence: true,
          length: {maximum: 3}, numericality: { only_integer: true },
          if: Proc.new { |e| e.points_required.blank? }
```

This works to ensure that each field is formatted properly. However, if a model is saved with both a `percentage_attendance_required` and `points_required` value it still passes validation, which is not what I want.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure you can combine these into the existing validations to DRY things up, but `validates_absence_of` is what you're looking for.

```
validates :points_required, absence: true, 
          if: Proc.new { |e| e.percentage_attendance_required.present? }

validates :percentage_attendance_required, absence: true, 
          if: Proc.new { |e| e.points_required.present? }
```

Comment: Excellent! Thanks! This worked for me. It's actually just `:absence` in rails 4 though: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#absence

Comment: @AlexVallejo Fat fingered the "_of".  Fixed. Thanks!